# Ruby on Rails: PDFKit not display characters correctly in CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, centos, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I've been using PDFKit to create pdf in Rails 4 on Ubuntu 13.04. Locally, It works fine and show html page with utf-8 encoding, but when I want to get pdf created in server(CentOS) pdf will be created but the contents are weird charracters(some black squares). Even when I delete html content and put a letter the result is the same.

Any idea?

Comment: Check that the configuration should be same on both place.

Comment: it's already done dude.

Comment: Do all of the characters come out as black squares, or only a few of them? Also, are you using any special (non-ASCII) characters?

Comment: sorry for being late, yeah all of them are like what i explained. I removed all everything of content and type a word in plain English, but the result was the same.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to execute the following commands :

```
sudo -i yum install dejavu-sans-fonts
sudo -i yum install dejavu-sans-mono-fonts
```